# Drawing a line continuously via code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-graphics

I am totally new to iOS developing and I've got an idea in my mind but I do not know exactly how to implement it correctly.

What I need is my program to draw a line which can be controlled by the user by tapping buttons. It is kind of like the "snake" game. I tried out core graphics but it is not quite the right approach I guess. I did following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.02 target:self selector:@selector(updateGame:)    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)updateGame:(id)sender{

    double timeInterval= [self.lastDate timeIntervalSinceNow]*-1;

      for (int n=0; n<playerNum; n++) {

      CGPoint lastPoint=[[locationArray objectAtIndex:n]CGPointValue];

      CGPoint updatedLoc= CGPointMake(lastPoint.x+100*timeInterval*sin([[directionArray objectAtIndex:n]doubleValue]), lastPoint.y+60*timeInterval*cos([[directionArray objectAtIndex:n]doubleValue]));

      [locationArray replaceObjectAtIndex:n withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:updatedLoc]];

      [self.drawingView drawToBufferFrom:lastPoint to:updatedLoc withColor:[colorArray objectAtIndex:n]];



    }

self.lastDate=[NSDate date];
}
```

In DrawingView.m

```
-(void)drawToBufferFrom:(CGPoint)lastLoc to:(CGPoint)currentLoc withColor:(UIColor *)color{


//[color setStroke];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(offScreenBuffer, color.CGColor);
//CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(offScreenBuffer, 1, 0, 1, 1);
CGContextBeginPath(offScreenBuffer);
CGContextSetLineWidth(offScreenBuffer, 10);
CGContextSetLineCap(offScreenBuffer, kCGLineCapRound);

CGContextMoveToPoint(offScreenBuffer, lastLoc.x, lastLoc.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(offScreenBuffer, currentLoc.x, currentLoc.y);
CGContextDrawPath(offScreenBuffer, kCGPathStroke);

[self setNeedsDisplay];


}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGImageRef cgImage= CGBitmapContextCreateImage(offScreenBuffer);
UIImage* screenImage= [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
[screenImage drawInRect:self.bounds];
}
```

The direction changes by the user tapping on either side of the screen. 
However what I am facing is: Major lags on the device itself so I think there needs to be an easier way to draw those lines without any lags.

Answer (score 0):

UIBezierPath is easier, but a better way especially if you want to include overlays or sprites would be cocos2d or similar game dev framework...